# Two Dimensional Choose or Combination Problem in Statistics

Tags: statistics, permutations, combinations

I have a two-dimensional choose problem.

```
 x: 18  21  29      
 y: 28  38  48      
 z: 99  112 127 130 131
 AA: 11  22  12 23
 BB: 55 22 23 23 13 30 34
 CC: 9  3  21 23 33 44 53 343
```

I need to write all combinations that MUST include one each from x, y,z, AA, BB, CC rows.

One straight forward combination would be x-18, y-28, z-99, AA-11, BB-55, CC-9

I need help in figuring and writing down all combinations.

Comment: You need to *write them all down*? Even ignoring CC, there are hundreds, if I understand the objective correctly.

Comment: 10080 different ways to combine these items, if i understand correctly...

Comment: I need to write them all down.  This is my worst case list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am able to solve this using Python script:

```
import itertools
a = [[18,  21,  29], [28  38  48], [99  112 127 130 131], ...]
z=list(itertools.product(*a))
print z
```